# ASPxDateEdit: How can I show only the date component of a DateTime (ie, hide the time component)?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, datepicker, devexpress

I am using an ASPxDateEdit control for editing of a date field.  The time component of this particular field will never be relevant, so I'd like to hide it so that only the date component is visible.  I've tried the following:

`<dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="dpExpirationDate" EditFormat="Date" runat="server" />`

`<dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="dpExpirationDate" EditFormat="Custom" EditFormatString="M/d/yyyy" runat="server" />`

`<dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="dpExpirationDate" EditFormat="Custom" EditFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}" runat="server" />`

I am setting it like this:

`dpExpirationDate.Value = Entity.ExpirationDate`

No matter what I try, it still shows 7/9/2012 12:00:00 AM.  How can I hide the time component?

Also, someone with rep may wat to add `ASPxDateEdit` as a tag.

**Update:** I found the problem and it's very quirky, but what would one expect from a DevExpress control?

I've found that setting the ASPxDateEdit's Visible property to either True or False in the codebehind will cause it to show the time component regardless what you set for its EditFormat property.  Also, pushing in a date string will also result in the same effect, so don't try to assign `DateTime.Now.ToString()` to its Value property or you will experience the same results.

Comment: I use first version of your code in multiple pages and everything works as expected. I event tested in my page and I don't see time part of datetime.

Comment: I tried it in a test application and it works there, so something funny is going on with my main application.  I am going to have to tear everything apart and get back with you, at which point I'll have you repost your answer so I can mark it since you've put this much effort into it.

Comment: Filip, I tracked down the problem and posted an update in my question.  If you'd like to verify my results, feel free.  Repost your answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first variant works in my environment. So, set [EditFormat](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxDateEdit_EditFormattopic) attribute value to Date.
[EditFormat enumeration values.](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsEditFormatEnumtopic)
As for toggling Visible attribute, I couldn't reproduce this issue. However, there is an important difference between [Visible](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxEdit_Visibletopic) and [ClientVisible](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxEditBase_ClientVisibletopic) attributes. If you set Visible to false, control won't be rendered. So, you can't manipulate with it on client side. If you want control to render hidden, you must use ClientVisible attribute.